# No logro obtener el divisor correcto

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Tengo un programa el cual toma como parámetros una lista de números enteros positivos y un número entero positivo. La función devuelve la cuenta de cuantos de los números contenidos en la lista son divisibles por el número proporcionado como segundo parámetro.El codigo ue tengo es el siguiente:

main.py

```
import functions

numbers = [3, 8, 14, 33, 77, 2]
divisor = 2
found = functions.divisibles(numbers, divisor)
print("Hay", found ,"números divisibles por", divisor, "en", numbers)
```

functions.py

```
def divisibles(numbers, divisor):
    for elements in numbers:
        if elements in divisor == 0:
            result = elements // divisor
            return result
```

EL PROBLEMA DE ESTE PROGRAMA ES A LA HORA DE EJECUTAR Y NO SÉ PORQUE:

numbers = [3, 8, 14, 33, 77, 2]
divisor = 2
Resultado inesperado: '4'
Se esperaba: '3'

Comment: `elements in divisor`?? esto no te dara error?? no deberia ser  `elements / divisor` o incluso puedes usar divmod

Comment: Este código da error y no reproduce el resultado comentado. Por favor, aporta el código real que quieres que revisemos.

Comment: @JackNavaRow El código mencionado anteriormente no da error a la hora de ejecutarlo

Comment: @ChemaCortes El código expuesto anteriormente no me da ningun error a la hora de ejecutarlo. Lo único es que se me sumaba más 1 en el resultado final

Comment: @Gonzalo ¿sabes para que sirve `in`?, python es uno de los lenguajes donde es más sencillo leer los códigos, por ejemplo `in` viene del inglés *pertenece*, *dentro de*,  *en*,  en tu caso dices: `if elements in divisor == 0:` : si el valor de la variable elements esta dentro de `divisor == 0`. ¿`divisor == 0` es en donde buscaria elementos?, ¿en un conjunto?, pues no por lo que tu codigo deberia lanzarte un error

Comment: @Gonzalo El código de `functions.py` no es correcto. Si no te sale un error, es que estás usando otro fichero de código. Copia la función `divisibles` dentro de `main.py` y no importes nada.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad la mejor manera de realizar la función es la siguiente:

```
def divisibles(numbers, divisor):
    result = 0
    for number in numbers:
        if number % divisor == 0:
            result += 1

    return result
```

En el **if** el operado % obtiene el residuo de la operación, si se cumple se suma uno al contador o resultado y por último se retorna.

Answer (score 0):

En python, `//` sirve para hacer la división entera. Si quieres saber si es divisible tienes que hacer el modulo `%`.

Una posible implementación de divisibles:

```
def divisible(numbers, divisor):
        count = 0
        for element in numbers:
                if element % divisor == 0:
                        count += 1
        return result
```